# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add order by clause in my view but it is throwing an error.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

```
   ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test_booking]
   AS
    select NEWID() as UniqueKey, * from (
        SELECT  [startdatetime]           AS StartDateTime,    
               [bookingdatetime]         AS BookingDateTime, 
               [firstname]               AS firstname       
         FROM   [dbo].[vw_Testpatient] 
        WHERE  statusCode in (                       
        '2',    
        '0      
        )       
    ) T
    ORDER BY startdatetime DESC


GO
```

Comment: @DaleK, I want to use order by clause for startdatetime

Comment: @DaleK, I can see that but I am looking for a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it states - you cannot include an `ORDER BY` clause in the definition of a view. It is in much the same way that the order of data returned from a table when no ORDER BY is applied on the SELECT means that the order of data is not guaranteed.

Apply the `ORDER BY` in the queries that SELECT from the view instead.

Instead of

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test_booking]  
AS  
 select NEWID() as UniqueKey, * 
 from (
    SELECT  [startdatetime]           AS StartDateTime,    
           [bookingdatetime]         AS BookingDateTime, 
           [firstname]               AS firstname       
    FROM   [dbo].[vw_Testpatient] 
    WHERE  statusCode in (                       
    '2',    
    '0      
 )       
) T
ORDER BY startdatetime DESC
```

Apply it like

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vw_Test_booking
ORDER BY StartDateTime  DESC
```

Comment: I do not want to create another view to get the data from `select * from...` Is there any way to include it in the view itself.

Comment: @MVC you don't have to create another view... you order it where you **use** the view.

Comment: @DaleK, I understand your point. The problem here is that I need to modify the code then but I don't want to touch the code. As this is already a working view so I thought if there is any way to modify the view itself then it would be great.

Comment: You can't help but have to change the code this time. But if you want to avoid changing the code in future, put the select inside a stored procedure.

Comment: @DaleK, got it. Thank you for your time.